# An unexpected error occurred: "/home/kudzie/portfolio/package.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 575"

Tags: json

trying to build a GitHub portfolio and host it on Namecheap so having this error: An unexpected error occurred: "/home/kudzie/portfolio/package.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 575".

```
     {
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "yarn run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "homepage":{
          "http://kgomera.me/."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

trying to build a GitHub portfolio and host it on Namecheap so having the error l posted above

Comment: Use https://jsonlint.com/ to check the JSON.  There is a mistake on line 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your "homepage" line:

```
"homepage":{
    "http://kgomera.me/."
}
```

it is expecting a property, but all that's there is a string.

There are a couple ways of fixing this. The first, which is probably the way you're intending, is to change `"homepage"` from an object to a property:

```
"homepage":"http://kgomera.me/."
```

Secondly, you could add a key to make it into a property

```
"homepage":{
    "url":"http://kgomera.me/."
}
```

Or lastly, you could make it into an array instead of an object by replacing the curly brackets with square brackets

```
"homepage":[
    "http://kgomera.me/."
]
```

Just for future situations like this, [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) is a fantastic JSON validator and formatter that tells you exactly what is happening.

Comment: thank you with your help and l tried all the solutions and the first on came to be handy and managed to deploy my page